# Make it so that output is single "sheet" with unbounded width

Tags: width, varwidth

The first line of my TeX document is

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=10pt]{standalone}
```

The output generated is cropped to the width of the content, but it has a maximum width after which it wraps the content. I don't want that. I want the output to be as wide as it needs to be. What do I need to change about that line?

Comment: Don't use `varwidth`

Comment: @egreg But I want the width to vary according to the content.

Comment: @egreg Removing `vardwidth` results in all of the content occupying a single line.

Comment: And “as wide as it needs to be” means?